# When saying "looking good", do I use an adverb or an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Despite believing that I knew the rules behind the use of adjectives vs. adverbs in certain sentences, it feels like I could be missing some nuance somewhere.

For the sake of the question, let's use the example:

> You look good today.

Translating this I would produce:

> Vi aspektas bona hodiaŭ.

With the understanding that `bon-` should end with the adjective ending *a* since it describes a quality of the pronoun *vi*.

But I've also seen people write:

> Vi aspektas bone hodiaŭ.

And of course, I'd happily write:

> Mi fartas bone.

Since `bone` is describing how I'm faring (the action), not a direct attribute of me.

So it feels like my logic above is completely wrong, and that there should be an adverb following `aspektas` rather than an adjective.

Can someone provide a clearer explanation regarding the use of the adverb vs. adjective here? Which one is correct, and is there some nuance around it?

Comment: This question might provide some help: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/930/do-aspekti-and-ŝajni-go-with-adjectives-or-adverbs

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro Thanks – this pretty much covers what I was asking. Mods: if you want to close this as a dup of the linked question, I'm cool with that.

Comment: It's cool to see that somebody else thought of the same thing as I did :)